# Looping over long values from JSON and writing to console in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a JSON file structured like so in a file named 'Config.json':

```
    {
      "name": "Michael",
      "ids": [111111, 222222, 333333, 444444, 555555]
    }
```

I am deserializing it like so:

```
Config config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(File.ReadAllText("Config.json"));
```

I have a Config class like so:

```
class Config
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ids")]
        public long Ids{ get; set; }
    }
```

How do I iterate over the ids and write them to console? I have tried this:

```
    var ids = new List<long> { config.Ids};

    foreach (long id in ids)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id.ToString());
    }
```

But I get an error:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Int64' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly

I cannot figure out how to deserialize and write this...I have tried experimenting with different values (uint64) but the same error occurs.

Thanks so much!

Comment: `ids` is an array, no the single long value, `public long[] Ids` should be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ids` property in your Json is an array (as indicated by the square brackets). To properly desierialize this Json, your model class should look like

```cs
public class Config
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ids")]
    public IEnumerable<long> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

Then, if you want to write all of the values to console

```cs
foreach (var id in config.Ids)
{
    Console.WriteLine(id); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ids` is an array.

Change `public long Ids{ get; set; }` to `public long[] Ids { get; set; }` and print them like this:

```
    foreach (long id in config.Ids)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id.ToString());
    }
```